# Remove surrounding character when followed by another character

Tags: regex

I have the following characters:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

The goal of the regex is to find surrounding double-quotes when the last one is followed by a colon.
In the mentioned case, it should find the first two double-quotes alone, since the last of the two is followed by a colon.

I currently have the following regex: `((")+[^"]+"+:)`, which finds `"foo":`. What should I change so that it can select the double-quotes alone?

Comment: What output do you want exactly?

Comment: @Shafizadeh In the case that I would like to replace the target characters (the first double-quotes, in this exact case) from the original text, it would give me {foo:"bar"}

Comment: This smells `JSON`-like, why not use one of the beautiful functions then?

Comment: @Jan, I would prefer not go into to much details, since it is unrelated to the question, but the JSON generator I am using provides double-quotes for the key name, which I would like to remove.

Comment: So you want to go from `{"foo":"bar"}` to `{foo:"bar"}`?

Comment: @migg Yes, this is the wanted outcome if I were to use the regex in a find-and-replace context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just match `"+([^"]+)"+(?=:)` and replace it with `$1` as shown in this [example](https://regex101.com/r/uT3uT8/2). However this doesn't take into account any escaping and you might consider @Jan s comment of using a JSON-library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get you right .. But try this:

```
/{"(.*)(?:"):/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iI2dS0/1)

Comment: Why is everybody so keen on the dot-star soup? Isn't a `[^"]+` much more suitable here?

Comment: @Jan Yes it is, but my pattern is more readable for replacing *(methinks)*

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a **positive lookahead** like so:

```
"([^"]+)"(?=:)
```

See <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kV7oK2/1)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
/\{"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"\}/g
```

and replace with:

```
{$1:"$2"}
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/aX6lH8/1